# Solution of nonlinear second-order ODE $y''+\frac{(y'+2ax)^2+4b^2}{2y}+\frac{10}{3}a=0$

Tags: differential-equations

Is there any way of solving the following second-order ODE
$$y''+\frac{(y'+2ax)^2+4b^2}{2y}+\frac{10}{3}a=0,$$
where $a$ and $b$ are some constant?
If we know that one solution exists, how  would it help to possibly find another solution?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: OK - I apologize and remove my comment.

Comment: There is no reason to think there is a closed-form solution.

Answer (score 5):

Here are two rather special solutions:

$$ \eqalign{y \left( x \right) &=-\frac{a{x}^{2}}{3}-{\frac {3{b}^{2}}{4a}}\cr
y(x) &= -\frac{3a x^2}{2} - \frac{6 b^2}{a}\cr} $$

I don't think there is any way to use these to get more closed-form solutions.

Of course there are series solutions.

Comment: I really appreciate it. Could you please explain how do you obtain the solutions?

Comment: Guess there's a solution that's a quadratic and see what the coefficients have to be.